# PHP getting month dates and placing into array

Tags: php, arrays, date, datetime, days

Today I found this function that says how many days were in a month `cal_days_in_month()`. But what I am wanting to do is list all the days into array, something like this.

```
$days = array(
"2012-11-01","2012-12-01","2012-13-01"...etc
)
```

Could someone point me into the right direction?

Kind regards
Frank!

Answer (score 2):

```
$start    = new DateTime('first day of this month');
$end      = new DateTime('first day of next month');
$interval = DateInterval::createFromDateString('1 day');
$period   = new DatePeriod($start, $interval, $end);

foreach ($period as $dt)
{
  echo $dt->format("l Y-m-d") . PHP_EOL;
}
```

[See it in action](http://codepad.viper-7.com/3PHKgc)

**Reference**

- [DateTime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php)
- [DatePeriod](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateperiod.php)
- [DateInterval](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php)

Answer (score 0):

```
 $fromdate=strtotime(date("Y-m-d",mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, '01', $year)));
    $todate=strtotime(date("Y-m-t",mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, '01', $year)));

        for($i=$fromdate;$i<=$todate;$i++)
        {
        $i=$i+84600;
        echo     $nextdate[]=date('Y-m-d',$i);
        }
```