# Returning a report for each date in a PHP array

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date

What I am trying to do here is render a report for each date in the current month from a MYSQL table.

I have a table with rows in, which a lot have the same **date**. As you can see here[image: my MYSQL table with rows with duplicate dates in]

What I would like to do is for every date **in the current month** is see how many rows have been found in the MYSQL table for that date and then return it into an array. The final product will be a multidimensional array for every date in the current month. Something like this

```
array("dates"=>
array(
"1 feb"=>2, //the number of rows for that date found in the MYSQL table
"2 feb"=>8,
"3 feb"=>0
)
)
```

But the issue is I wouldn't have a clue where to start with the coding, like what PHP functions would I use? So I was hoping someone could push me in the right direction :)

Comment: You're going to do a select that groups by month and day. Look into `GROUP BY`, `MONTH`, and `DAY` at the MySQL website.

Comment: Do you have a table that contains every date?

Comment: FYI, naming your columns after reserved keywords is a bad thing to do.

Comment: Does this answer help? http://stackoverflow.com/a/366610/582278

Answer (score 0):

Probably not working code but should point you in the right direction:

```
SELECT 
    SUM(money) AS sum,
    `date`
FROM 
    money_table
WHERE
    MONTH(`date`) = 2
GROUP BY 
    DAY(`date`)
```

**Reference**

- [`GROUP BY`](http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysqlgroupby.php)
- [`MONTH`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_month)
- [`DAY`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_day)

Comment: But this doesn't loop through every date in the current month

Comment: You can use a `where` clause to do that. You know how your DB is set up so it's up to you to ultimately get this query to do exactly what you want.

Comment: It's not doing what I need it to do though, I want it to loop through every possible date in this month, if no rows are counted for that date then put a `0`

Comment: So write some code that combine the this answer with [the other answer i gave you](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14792217/php-getting-month-dates-and-placing-into-array). You're already 99% there. I'm happy to help you but I can't do all of your work for you.

Answer (score -1):

You said you didn't have a table with all the dates.  If you did, this would be trivial.  Let's say you had such a table called calendar.

```
select calendardate
, ifnull(sum(money), 0) sum_of_money
from calendar left join money on calendardate = money.date
where calendardate >= {d '2013-02-01'}
and calendardate < {d '2013-03-01'}
group by calendardate
```

Other things that could be stored in the calendar table are fiscal information and holidays.  It might be worth your while to create and maintain one.

Comment: -1 Make a new table with all the dates in? I'm confused why you would need to do that.